# How to remove comma from list in python

Tags: python

thanks for all the help but i read the documentation and found the answer

Comment: That's not comma. That's quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its a list as you intended or depicted, you just need to convert the strings to integers. Using built-in [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) would work for you

```
>>> some_list = ['1','2','3','4']
>>> map(int, some_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

An equivalent List Comprehension solution would be

```
>>> [int(e) for e in some_list]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: which one should be preferred of the above two methods?

Comment: Well, the former is more concise, and for builtins it has some performance advantage over List Comprehension. If the mapped function is a bit complex like lambda, then list comprehension should be preferred.